# What to do after service discovery using wifi direct on android?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, service-discovery, wifip2p

I implemented service discovery over wifi-direct and I am able to successfully discover the service using http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html . But I don't know what to do now? How do I connect to the service? the way I connect to other peers? how do I use a service over wifi-direct? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've discovered the service you should be able to connect to it as if it were [a regular WifiP2P client](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#connect).  From there, you can get the IP address of the group owner (which may be either device) and set up a connection (over a Socket, for example).

Comment: Thanks :) , although I figured it out already. Do you know if it's possible to send data without connecting?

Comment: You can send data in the discovery phase by putting it in the WifiP2pServiceInfo, but after forming a network you have to use a Socket or something similar.